# How to use User Stylesheets to customize the style of some websites, without using a third party browser extension?

Tags: html, css, browser, userstyles

I know the [Stylus](https://github.com/openstyles/stylus) and Stylish (not recommended) browser extensions that can re-style a given website (basically by customizing CSS).

In [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318178/new-feature-add-a-night-mode-button#comment316770_318178), the author states this can be done via "user stylesheets".

**How is it possible to use "user stylesheets" to modify the style of www.example.com and a different style for www.example2.com?**

Is it something that can be done without requiring a third-party browser extension, if so, how/where in the browser options should we add our custom CSS?

Comment: This is not a standard feature of many ( if any ) browsers afaik - perhaps this might be of interest https://davidwalsh.name/firefox-user-stylesheet or this https://www.lostsaloon.com/technology/using-a-custom-stylesheet-in-a-web-browser/ ~ this latter link suggests that ALL modern browsers allow this ....

Comment: @RamRaider Thank you for your comment. The link seems outdated. I'm on Chrome, and there is no `User StyleSheets` folder (*"Depending on the browser version and OS this could vary but check the configuration folder on your system under the folder <user-profile>/Default/User StyleSheets/. Also if there is no file named Custom.css then you will need to create one inside the folder User StyleSheets/."*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be deprecated nowadays:

https://codereview.chromium.org/66383005/

> Remove the concept of user stylesheets.
>   -The support for this has been removed from Chromium already.
>   This is now just deleting dead code.
>   ...